# Roles Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, roles

I have implemented Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.6 based on Fabric-Samples. I need to create a user who can run invoke and another user who can only run query. I also need to create a member: what is a member: is it a client, or a peer or an orderer or an admin? what is a readers, a writers (I don't understand)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question step-by-step:

1. What is a member?

Ans: Fabric has 4 roles: orderer, peer, client, and admin. When none of these types are specified while registering the identity with Fabric CA, by default the identity is considered to be the **member** of that particular organization.

2. What are Readers, Writers, and Admins?

These are policies. NOTE: `Admins` is the policy and the `admin` is a role. Then you specify policies for different access levels (for e.g. `"OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"`).

3. How to provide one identity to just invoke while other to just query?

As far as I understand, by default the `Writers` can invoke the chaincode, while the `Readers` can query the chaincode. An expected behavior is that whoever is invoking the chaincode should also be able to query it.

Comment: As roles and policies are quite limited, maybe the best option for point 3 is to control it at chaincode level. For instance, you provide your custom "role" certificate attribute when registering an identity in the CA and after that you provide a layer in your chaincode so that ACLs are checked against that attribute (or even MPS IDs or whatever) for every chaincode operation. That is, very simplified, how I usually implement ACLs. This way, operations susceptible to update the ledger can be allowed only to some "role" (although any client can try to invoke or query).